# SDL file not found while executing Makefile

Tags: c, macos, makefile, compilation, sdl

Im working with C on MacOS, when i compile the program by myself with

```
gcc main.c -o prog $(sdl2-config --cflags --libs)
```

It works fine, but when i try to make it work with a makefile i keep facing this error

```
gcc -o main.o -c main.c prog 
clang: warning: prog: 'linker' input unused [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
main.c:1:10: fatal error: 'SDL.h' file not found
#include <SDL.h>
```

There is my code

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    SDL_Window *window = NULL;

    if ( SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) != 0) 
    {
        SDL_Log("Unable to initialize SDL: %s", SDL_GetError()); 
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    }

    window = SDL_CreateWindow("Bomberman", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 800, 600, SDL_WINDOW_MINIMIZED); 
    if (window == NULL)
    {
        SDL_Log("Unable to create window: %s", SDL_GetError()); 
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    bool window_open = true; 
    
    while (window_open)
    {

        SDL_Event event;
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event))  
        {
            if (event.type == SDL_QUIT) 
            {
                window_open = false; 
            }
        }
    }
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window); 
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

And here is my makefile

```
main.o: main.c
    gcc -o main.o -c main.c prog $(sdl2-config --cflags --libs)
```

Comment: It's almost always a code smell to use make's `shell` function in a recipe.  The recipe is ALREADY running in a shell.  Using the `shell` function just leads to confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Well, look at the command you ran from the compile line:

```
gcc main.c -o prog $(sdl2-config --cflags --libs)
```

This builds an output `prog` from the source file.  And compare it to your recipe:

```
gcc -o main.o -c main.c prog $(sdl2-config --cflags --libs)
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

They aren't the same, so clearly you won't get the same result.  Plus you've told make you're trying to build the output file `main.o`, not `prog` as your command line version does.

First, remove the extra stuff and fix the target.

Second, `$` is special to make (it introduces a make variable).  So in your makefile recipe `$(sdl2-config --cflags --libs)` is actually expanding a very oddly-named make variable.

You want this:

```
prog: main.c
        gcc main.c -o prog $$(sdl2-config --cflags --libs)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make already defines a builtin rule for building .o files from .c files with the same base name.  You should use that and the standard FLAGS variables.  So you end up wanting something like:

```
CFLAGS = $$(sdl2-flags --cflags)
LDLIBS = $$(sdl2-flags --libs)
```

With just that, you can type `make main.o` to compile main.o and `make main` to build an executable `main` from main.o (if it exists) or main.c (if there's no main.o already)

If you want to build prog, you can add a rule

```
prog: main.o
        $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LDLIBS)
```

Comment: It's not enough to just use `$(LINK.o)`.  The built-in recipe for linking things is `$(LINK.o) $^ $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS) -o $@`.  You can omit `LOADLIBES` because it's just there for backward-compat, but you need the rest.